# Can't prevent form posting on hitting return on text input

Tags: javascript

In my code example when you put your cursor in one of the two input fields and then press ENTER on your keyboard, a timestamp number is displayed in a div underneath. Press ENTER again and it changes.

If you take one of the text fields out so there's only one, then form seems to post (reload the page).

I can't figure out why this happens when there's only one input field.

```js
function handleKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13)
    document.getElementById('theButton').click();
}
function theFunc() {
  document.getElementById("theTime").innerHTML = Math.floor(Date.now());
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="textInput" onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput2" onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="theButton" onclick="theFunc()">
</form>

<div id="theTime"></div>
```

Comment: It appears when only one input is on a form pressing enter will submit the 
form.  http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2 "When there is only one single-line text input field in a form, the user agent should accept Enter in that field as a request to submit the form."

As @Will pointed out, adding event.preventDefault() to your code will prevent it from submitting.  This code will prevent event propagation at the input's keypress handler before the submit event handler has a chance to fire.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The only problem with `event.preventDefault` is that it won't allow ANY text to be entered. I tried adding it after `if (event.keyCode == 13)` but the form still submits.

Comment: what browser are you using?  I'm running my fiddle in chrome 63 and no submit on enter keypress.  My prevent default is in the event.keyCode == 13 condtional which maybe helps https://jsfiddle.net/3c9neqb1/

Comment: Firefox, and after more research I believe it's a problem unique to FF.

Answer (score 0):

**Event.preventDefault()**

```js
function handleKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13)
    event.preventDefault(); // magic
    document.getElementById('theButton').click();
}

function theFunc() {
  document.getElementById("theTime").innerHTML = Math.floor(Date.now());
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="textInput" onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event)"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="theButton" onclick="theFunc()">
</form>

<div id="theTime"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with your code is it prevents entering *any* text.

Comment: The only way around it I can see is to add an empty hidden input field, which is just icky.

Comment: Just move the preventDefault.

Comment: After more research I believe it's a problem unique to Firefox.